# Load R package from character string

Tags: string, r, character

I want to create a function which includes loading a package that I make within the function.  A short example (which doesn't run!):

```
loadMe <- function(name){
    genLib(xxx, libName = name) #make a new library with name "name"
    library(name)               #load the new library...
}
```

This does not work!  A bit of reproducible code which illustrates my main problem:

```
library(ggplot)         #this works fine
load.this <- "ggplot"
library(load.this)      #I want this to load ggplot!
```

I know the problem is that `library()` and `require()` take as an argument an object name which does not exist yet.  I have tried wrapping my character string with `parse()`, `deparse()`, `substitute()`, `expression()`, `quote()`, etc etc.  These all return the same problem:

```
library(load.this)
# Error in library(loadss) : there is no package called 'loadss'
library(deparse(load.this))
# Error in library(deparse(loadss)) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you look at help to library (`?library`) then you got (in Argument section): "`package`  the name of a package, given as a name or literal character string, or a character string, depending on whether `character.only` is `FALSE` (default) or `TRUE`."

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the `character.only` argument

```
foo <- "ggplot2"
library(foo,character.only=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have tried using `parse()`. The following seems to work for me:

```
eval(parse(text = 'library(MASS)')[1])
```

Comment: Avoid parse. Use substitute instead

Comment: @hadley: Why avoid `parse`? How can you get `substitute` to achieve the same results in this context? I am thinking of the case when I don't know a priori which library should be loaded, although I might have it as a text string.

Comment: You always want to use the type of object that provides the best representation of the problem.  To use substitute you'd do: `substitute(library(pkg), list(pkg = as.name("MASS")))`